# Как получить дробную часть числа в MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Например, SQL запрос выдает сумму (деньги) - 67889.87, т.е. 67889 рублей и 87 копеек. Чтобы получить целую часть, несложно - используем `floor`:

```
select value, floor(value)
from table t
where t.id = ...
```

Как получить дробную часть как целую, чтобы вернул 87?

Comment: Может быть (поле*100)%100 или скажем (поле-floor)*100

Comment: а если число = 10.001 то какой результат вы ожидаете получить ? 1) 001 ,2) 1

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan там копейки, .001 не может быть (по идее), ожидаю получить 1.

Comment: @Mike думал, есть функция, которая сразу выдаст нужное. Как вариант ещё есть `round(mod(value, 1) * 100)`. Оформите как ответ свой комментарий?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Специальных функций для получения десятичной дробной части, как целого в MySQL нет. Можно воспользоваться, например:

```
select (value*100)%100
 или
select (value-floor(value))*100
```

Comment: не подскажете, почему появляется погрешность, и без `round` выводит `86.000000324`?

Comment: @Denis Оно же наверняка в float типе считает, похоже на обычную погрешность для данного типа

Answer (score 0):

Можно вот так :

```
select value%1
```

Comment: Прочтите, пожалуйста, вопрос внимательней. Что вернёт, например, 1.5%1?